# Will Linux as a guest be able to make use of hardware support of a Windows host?

Tags: linux, windows, hardware-compatibility

I have a Radeon HD 7790 which apparently won't work as well in Linux (haven't tried it yet).

My idea is to install Windows as the host and do the Linux work in a VM (which involves stuff that needs 3D acceleration). Could this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the software you use. Most support some level of 3D now - VMware Workstation and VirtualBox both do to some extent.

as an aside I have a HD7790 at home and it works fine under Ubuntu 13.04. Use either the open source radeon driver OR get the newest from AMD's website though. The one that comes with Ubuntu is too old to properly recognize the card.

Comment: I usually use Fedora though, I think it should ship the latest drivers - right? And are you sure that 3D accel. works fine? Is it better than what I'd get in a VM?

Comment: The question is what VM software you would use. Fedora definitely can take advantage of the 3D acceleration on your HD77xx card.

Comment: I usually use VirtualBox. "Fedora definitely can take advantage of the 3D acceleration on your HD77xx card." - how do you know? From all I've gathered the 7790 support isn't very great on Linux...

Comment: Because I have run Fedora on my PC at home, although I run Ubuntu normally & have a HD77xx video card. Not sure who told you it does not work under Linux but you can either use the drivers that come with the OS or download newer (but proprietary) drivers from ATI's site. I run Steam's DotA2 and Counterstrike 2 natively problems as well as a bunch of older games via wine. The biggest gripe I have is that sound over HDMI only gives me stereo. Try this link: http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/RadeonHD7790CatalystPerformanceDriver.aspx

Comment: So you've used Fedora on your HD7790 and it works? That'd be great. But still, if it works better via VirtualBox, I'd prefer that solution, as there is some Windows software I'd like to run (and as I have a fairly small SSD I don't want to dual boot).

Comment: Yes but only with the xorg driver (radeon), I use the ATI driver now (required by steam). Not reason it wouldn't run in Fedora, ATI says it's a supported platform

Comment: What do you mean by "only with radeon driver"? If you're using the ATI one and it works too?